# Is Azure Point-To-Site VPN secure enough to use for 3rd party access?

Tags: security, sql-server, vpn, ftp, azure

I need to give some customers access to my server(Azure VM) via either FTP or SQL (they want to retrieve files via FTP and want to connect to a special database), no remote desktop.

Currently I'm using Azure's P2S VPN for this (I gave them the client-installer and client certificate), is this good enough for this kind of purpose? should I keep other security concerns in mind?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Point-to-Site (P2S) configuration lets you create a secure connection from an individual client computer to a virtual network. **VPN connection over SSTP (Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol).** I find a similar qustion with you, you could refer to this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/645112/how-to-keep-azure-point-to-site-vpn-secure).

Based on my experience, it is very important for you to replace certificate regularly. **Also, you need open suitable ports on Azure NSG and your VM firewall**. More information about Azure NSG please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).